Axios 404 error while trying to delete note ASP, Axios
I'm a beginner as an ASP.NET and React dev and I'm trying to create a CRUD project. I'm stuck at the DELETE request. I'm getting 404 error when I'm trying to delete note.
But in Swagger, everything works fine and I have access to note through the URL, in CORS all methods allowed, axios function getting the correct id.
Here's the ASP.NET delete method:
[HttpDelete("{Id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(DeleteNoteRequest request, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var note = await _dbContext.Notes.FindAsync(request.Id);

    if (note == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    _dbContext.Notes.Remove(note);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(ct);

    return NoContent();
}

axios function:
export const deleteNote = async (Id) => {
  try {
    var response = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:5109/notes/${Id}`, {
      data: {foo: 'bar'}
    });
    console.log(response.status, response.statusText)
    return response.status;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }

App.jsx
const onDelete = async (id) => {
    await deleteNote(id);
    let notes = await fetchNotes(filter);
    setNotes(notes);
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <div className="main">
        <NoteForm filter={filter} setFilter={setFilter} onCreate={onCreate} />
        <ul>
          {notes.map((n) => (
            <li key={n.id}>
              <Note
                id={n.id}
                title={n.title}
                description={n.description}
                createdAt={n.createdAt}
                onDelete={onDelete}
              />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
  );

Note.jsx
import React from "react";
import "./Note.css";
import moment from "moment";

const Note = ({ id, title, description, createdAt, onDelete }) => {

  const removeNote = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onDelete(id);
    console.log(id);
  };

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <div className="note-body">
        <p className="description">{description}</p>
        <p className="date">{moment(createdAt).format("DD/MM/YYYY")}</p>
        <button onClick={removeNote} className="delete-bttn">Удалить</button>
        <button  className="edit-bttn">
          Редактировать
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Note;

I read that axios doesn't support content type and add a 'trick' in axios function. Without it, I get a http 415 error

Please find the http request information from the browser develop tool, we need to find the url and payload etc. And you also can use postman to test it, waiting for your update.
